# Accessing JavaScript Sub-properties by Name

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following JavaScript function (part of a larger "class") to help ensure anybody using the object stores attribute values in the "values" property.

```
function _updateAttributes(attribute, value) {
    _attributes[attribute] = { values: { value: value }};
}
```

It works fine for a flat structure, but falls apart when I start trying to use it for sub-properties.

After running the following code:

```
myEntity.updateAttribute('name', 'Frankenstein');
myEntity.updateAttribute('name.source', 'John Doe');
```

I'd like the following structure:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": {
            "values": {
                "value": "Frankenstein"
            },
            "source": {
                "values": {
                    "value": "JohnDoe"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, it's coming out like this:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": {
            "values": {
                "value": "Frankenstein"
            }
        },
        "name.source": {
            "values": {
                "value": "JohnDoe"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any clean way to write this JavaScript or will I be faced with splitting out the strings and manually building the structure?

**NOTE:** I realize even the preferred structure is a little odd, but there's a Java object I'm mapping to that expects this format, so I don't have any options here.

Comment: Why do you consider parsing the strings (i.e. splitting by dots) as unclean? Yes, you will have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to parse the string (`parse` is a bit strong, just a single `split('.')` with a loop).

But frankly, the cleaner way would simply be:

```
myEntity.name = {values: 'Frankenstein'};
myEntity.name.source = {values: 'John Doe'};
```

Comment: I updated my post and removed the term "JSON". The "values" key is part of my Java object. I agree; it's silly.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your cleaner approach. I, perhaps abusively, stripped out additional properties when posting because they weren't necessarily relevant to the answer (in other words, the structure is more complicated than it appears). Essentially, the code is starting to look messy (in my humble opinion), but I'm starting to think I'm doing it at the expense of code quality.